# Exporting a selected row to PDF in react kendo grid

Tags: reactjs, kendo-grid

I wanted to create a kendo grid in my application using React and was successful in enabling sorting, filtering, pagination etc., as given in the [demo](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/).

What I want is to add a button to every row in the grid like **Export PDF**. On click of that button, it should export only that particular row to PDF. Is this functionality possible? All I have seen till now is exporting all the items to PDF. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to achieve this by making use of Editing(Inline) in Kendo React grid- https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/editing/editing-inline/
to add a button to each row and capture the data item selected. Finally I made use of PDF export functionality of Kendo to export only that particular row data to PDF.